# textinput event in jquery not triggering in IE. Any Alternative to capture textchange?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have a contenteditable div. I want to capture textinput event for contenteditable div. But ,its not working in IE. Is there any alternative for 'textchange' event ?

```
document.getElementById("div").addEventListener("textInput", function () {
  alert("contenteditable fires input"); });
```

Thanks

Comment: fiddle ::: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7VQxd/15/)

Comment: In IE browser, the event is executed when the input has losed the focus

Answer (score 1):

For IE `textinput` works and for other browsers `textInput` works, notice The Uppercase 'i'. So, first check user agent using javascript and then set the string accordingly. I've updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aminur/7VQxd/16/). Also here is the code snippet below:

```js
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
var eventListenerString;
if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))
  eventListenerString = "textinput";
else
  eventListenerString = "textInput";

document.getElementById("div").addEventListener(eventListenerString, function () {
   alert("contenteditable fires input"); 
});

document.getElementById("textarea").addEventListener(eventListenerString, function () {
   alert("textarea fires input"); 
});
```

```css
#div{ background: red; width: 200px; height: 100px;}
#textarea{ background: blue; width: 200px; height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div contenteditable id="div"></div>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Comment: no need for UAS sniffing...
browser will only fire the event method it supports.
inputEl.addEventListener('textinput',mytxtInput);inputEl.addEventListener('textInput',mytxtInput);... FX does not support it at all.

Answer (score 0):

may be this could help you:

```
$("Your selector here").change(function()
{
//Your code here
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work for div contenteditable. Its working for input types and textarea